# AWS Elasticache name resolution issue on high traffic

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

guys

I'm facing a problem with an Elasticache Cluster with Redis when I have high traffic (1.6k requests/sec) on the web servers.

The problem is the clusters name (configuration endpoint), PHP start to fail with:

```
018-08-27 14:02:03 - 51.36.136.47 - Redis::connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution - https://myserver.com/re.php?id=qZ2pfKmeqqpofKg=&p1=M2018082712-dc6872150731b24433b8592f6455f50e&p2=83721 - SA - /home/ubuntu/myapp/system/api/LRedis.php - 25 - errno: 2
```

If I use a quarter of the total traffic works fine.

Actually, I'm using the private IP address from one node and works, but this is not a good practice.

Comment: I solved the problem installing a DNS cache with dnsmasq on the server.

Comment: Did you find any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem just yesterday and did some workaround:

- change the redis instance type to allow higher network performance
- since I use Kubernetes environment, I increased kube-dns

And didn't see this issue coming up again, hope this helps.